# Handling error messages on mobile when there are many fields

Tags: error-message, validation

I am designing  a signup form that has the following fields in it:

- Username
- Email
- Password
- Confirm Password
- Where did you hear about us?

I have to show validation errors in these fields.

There are a couple of options in my mind:

1. Show a tooltip on each field (Tooltip might hide other fields)
2. Showing a popup with a summary of errors (Not a good idea)
3. Showing placeholders in each field with examples then showing an error message on signup. (Can password fields have example placeholder?)

**Any idea on how to handle this situation?**

Here's the Screen:

[image]

Comment: Hi Armin, welcome to the UX SE community. It seems you haven't done enough research on your own about the topic before posting the question. Doing a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=mobile+error+handling+ux) on the topic gives a lot of relevant references. Not to mention that Android and iOS have comprehensive guides to how errors should be shown in forms

Comment: Hi @ShreyasTripathy, I have done some research but, None of the cases match with my situation. I guess I should an image to the question.

Comment: [This](https://usersnap.com/blog/error-messages-best-practices) link, which is literally the first result in the Google search, should answer all of your queries.

Comment: I have read this article. As you can see, there's not enough space in my design to show underline error.

Comment: then your design is maybe not optimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a good summary:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/09/how-to-design-error-states-for-mobile-apps/

**Preventing errors in the first place** is the big thing, but sometimes mistakes will inevitably arise, in which case you need to think about:

- Right time of informing about errors (or success)
- Right place for validation output
- Right color for the message
- Clear language for your message

Your popup idea is not good on mobile so I'd recommend abandoning that. Tooltips in fields tend to be a no-go in UX because they disappear onFocus.

Go read the article and have a think what will work best for your problem. But the real secret is preventing errors in the first place!